# How to leave Powershell Loop (while) after Success?

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a Powershell-Command until my command `foo.bar` successfull finished.

Therefore I have build a loop:

```
foo.bar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if (!$lastexitcode) {
                while (!$lastexitcode) {
                    Write-Output -InputObject "Retrying foo.bar in 2 Minutes ..."
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
                    foo.bar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
                    }
```

My Script is jumping into the loop, but will never leave it. So I'm runinng in a infinity-loop. Whats wrong?

Comment: A powershell command won't set $lastexitcode.  Try $? instread.

Comment: For non-executables you'll want to test `$?` (`$false` if last command invocation failed, `$true` otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! This helped me out:

```
$maxretry = 3
while ($true -and $maxretry -gt 0) {
    foo.bar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($?) {
        break # Break the Loop on Success
    }
    else {
        $maxretry -= 1
        Write-Output -InputObject "foo.bar is still pending! Retrying for '$maxretry' times! Waiting for 2 Minutes ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds #120
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [$?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#section-1) automatic variable. It will be true if the last command succeeded. I would simplify the loop like this:

```bsh
while ($true) {
    foo.bar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($?) {
        # leave the loop on success
        break
    }
    # retry on error
    Write-Output -InputObject "Retrying foo.bar in 2 Minutes ..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
}
```

Note that this will not always work, it depends on how your `foo.bar` command handles the error action parameter. There could still be terminating errors so your `if` is never reached.

It might be more straight-forward to use a try-catch-construct:

```bsh
while ($true) {
    try {
        foo.bar
        break
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output -InputObject "Retrying foo.bar in 2 Minutes ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120 
    }
}
```